# apache2 with load balancer ignoring a server

Tags: apache, tomcat, ubuntu

i have single ubuntu machine running apache2 with 2 instances of tomcat (tomcat1,tomcat2).
tomcat1 is on port 8080, tomcat2 is on 9180.
i followed all the instructions on setting up load balancing but i get strange behavior.
if tomcat1 is up everything works. the requests reach both tomcats (i checked the logs).
but if tomcat1 is down i get "503 service unavailable" errors.
and it also works if tomcat1 is up by itself.
its like apache must have tomcat1 to work and will only see tomcat2 if tomcat1 is up.
here are all the config files i could think of including.

apache2.conf: didn't change it from installation default

mods-enabled/jk.conf: also not much changes, just did

```
JkWorkersFile /etc/apache2/workers.properties
```

workers.properties:

```
worker.list=balancer,status
worker.node1.port=8009
worker.node1.host=localhost
worker.node1.type=ajp13
worker.node1.ping_mode=A
worker.node1.lbfactor=1 
worker.node2.port=9109
worker.node2.host=localhost
worker.node2.type=ajp13
worker.node2.ping_mode=A
worker.node2.lbfactor=1
worker.balancer.type=lb
worker.balancer.balance_workers=node1,node2
worker.balancer.sticky_session=1
worker.status.type=status
```

sites-enabled/default-000:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin me@domain.commmm
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
       Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
       Order deny,allow
       Deny from all
       Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

    JKMount / balancer
</VirtualHost>
```

help in solving this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ok sorry - the 503 was being thrown from the ec2 loadblanacer that this server was sitting under. the config above actually works. all i had to do was chamge the ec2 loadbalancer health check to look at port 80(apache) instead of 8080(tomcat1).